# finding a preorder of some digits with their levels in BST

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a list that has e.g. 5 digits which each digit has its own level in `BST` :

list-->

```
[digit :6  level:1, digit :3  level:2, digit :5   level:3, digit :2 level:3, digit:1   level:4]
```

how can I find its preorder which is { 6,3,2,1,5} ?

Consider that I have 10000 digits in my list above.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To traverse a BST in preorder you have to
1. Visit the root (i.e. your number)
2. Traverse the left subtree.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

Each subtree is recursively traversed in the same way (root, left and right).

In your example you don't have a clear indication of which number is to the left or right of which. Once you get to your 10000 digits of your list, you will have many numbers at the same level (say level 20) and unless your list is structured in a better way that represents the BST you wont manage.

Just by saying digit: 65 is at level:20, you have no indication whether it is to the left of digit:70 at level:19 or to the right of digit: 60 at level: 19.

UPDATE (as indicated by Anil):

The position of each node in the tree can be determined by analysing the two levels above it. As described by Anil, the lowest common ancestor will determine whether a number A at level X should be to the left of number B or number C at Level X-1, depending on whether their common parent node at level X-2 is smaller or greater than A.

Given that pre-order is depth-first you'll have to iterate (or recursively process) through the list multiple times i'm afraid. If you don't have any limitations of memory you could build the tree first.

Comment: can you give a more concrete example where it could be ambiguous? I think one can unambiguously construct a binary tree with in-order and level-order traversals. Since it is mentioned as a binary search tree, sorted order of digits is the in-order traversal. Specifically for your example, position of 65 can be obtained by comparing it with the LCA of 60 and 70.

Comment: @Anil - he never stated it was in-order traversal, and in fact it is not. In-order would have started from Digit 1: Level 4, and in fact it is Level-order.  I am just saying that the way the question was posted, i.e. the way the levels were output you can't output the preorder of the BST. Lets say I give you:    [digit: 60 level 1, digit: 50 level 2, digit: 70 level 2, digit: 65 level: 3]  you could have preorder:  60, 50, 65, 70  or 60, 50, 70, 65. which one is the right preorder? You cant know because level order doesnt preserve the branch information.

Comment: I think you missed the fact that the question refers to binary search trees. For your example, 65 will be a left child of 70 since it is greater than 60 = LCA(50, 70) and less than 70. Now, regarding in-order traversal - since we have a BST at hand, a sorted list of all the input digits gives us its in-order traversal. Basically, we have in-order traversal and level-order traversal with us - we need to determine the actual tree!

Comment: @Anil - ah ok, now I got your point with the LCA. Yes I guess that will work to determine left and right children, I overlooked that. I will update my answer.