# Binary tree from in-order and level-order traversals?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Can we prove that one can unambiguously construct a binary tree from its in-order and level-order traversals?

I am thinking of a proof by induction on number of levels.

Base case: trees with 1 or 2 levels. These cases are clear.

Assume that this holds for trees with l levels. That is: one can unambiguously construct a binary tree with l levels from  its in-order and level-order traversals.

Inductive case: prove that this holds for trees with l+1 levels. Not clear how to proceed in this case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Huh... just curious, is this homework? :)

Comment: Sorry, had to mention it before. No, it is not a homework. I am trying to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539698/finding-a-preorder-of-some-digits-with-their-levels-in-bst and I am sure, it can be solved if we have a proof for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about proof, but the alg for doing so would be along the lines,

```
f(inorder, levelorder):
      if length(levelorder) == 0:
          return None
      root = levelorder[0]#set root to first element in levelorder
      subIn1, subIn2 = partition(inorder, levelorder[0]) #partition inorder based on root
      subLevel1 = extract(levelOrder, subIn1)#remove elements in level order not in subIn1
      subLevel2 = extract(levelOrder, subIn2)#remove elements in level order not in subIn2
      root->left = f(subIn1, subLevel1)
      root->right = f(subIn2, subLevel2)
      return root
```

To prove it you would have to show that the sequence left of a root node in an inorder traversal is an inorder traversal of the left subtree, and then the same for the right.  True, but tedious to prove.

You would also need to show that levelorder is maintained for subtrees. Also true, but tedious to prove.

Oh yeah, you may have to prove that the first element in a level order traversal is the root of a tree, but that should come from the definition.

Comment: Can you please explain what does the `extract` function do?

Comment: The extract function needs to return the intersection of levelOrder and subIn, maintaining the order in levelOrder.

Answer (score 6):

I have given this tutorial on my blog a)  - INORDER Traversal 
-POSTORDER Traversal

OR

b)  -INORDER Traversal 
    -PREORDER Traversal

We usually get Questions like :-

Create Binery tree from following tree Traversals

1)

> ```
> Inorder:   E  A  C  K  F  H  D  B  G
> Preorder:  F  A  E  K  C  D  H  G  B
> ```

HERE the most important think to ALWAYS remember is :-

> In **PREorder**  *FIRST* element is ROOT of the tree
>
> In **POSTorder**  *LAST* element is ROOT of the tree

I hope you got it :P

i.e considering 1) Question

1)  Inorder:   E  A  C  K  F  H  D  B  G
    Preorder:  F  A  E  K  C  D  H  G  B

**F**  is root

**E  A  C  K** will go to LEFT SUB TREE  of Root

**H  D  B  G** will go to RIGHT SUB TREE of Root

```
Step 1)
```

Now as we know which one is Root So...

```
                     F
                   /  \
        ( E A C K)      (H D B G) 


Step 2)
```

Now FOR LEFT SUB TREE we have 
E A C K from Inorder and same letters A  E  K  C  from Preorder

i.e

```
 Inorder   E A C K
 Preorder A E K C
```

now have found **A** as Root again so now tree is

```
                     F
                   /   \
                  A      (H D B G) 
                /  \
               E    (C K)


Step 3)
```

Now letters are

```
Inorder   C K
Preorder  K C
```

So now tree is

```
                           F
                         /   \
                        A     (H D B G) 
                      /  \
                     E    K
                         /
                        C
```

Same procedure can be done on Right Sub tree Of root F

For Postorder we have to find Root as the last element in traversal....

Colorfull version or this can be seen here http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2012/11/construction-of-binary-tree-from.html  :P

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code should work -

```
/*
//construct a bst using inorder & levelorder traversals.
//inorder    - 5, 10, 20, 50, 51, 55, 60, 65, 70, 80
//levelorder - 50, 10, 60, 5, 20, 55, 70, 51, 65, 80
         50
      /      \
    10        60
   /  \       /  \
  5   20    55    70
            /     /  \
          51     65    80
 */
struct node *construct_bst3(int inorder[], int levelorder[], int in_start, int in_end)
{
    static int levelindex = 0;
    struct node *nnode = create_node(levelorder[levelindex++]);

    if (in_start == in_end)
        return nnode;

    //else find the index of this node in inorder array. left of it is left subtree, right of this index is right.
    int in_index = search_arr(inorder, in_start, in_end, nnode->data);

    //using in_index from inorder array, constructing left & right subtrees.
    nnode->left  = construct_bst3(inorder, levelorder, in_start, in_index-1);
    nnode->right = construct_bst3(inorder, levelorder, in_index+1, in_end);

    return nnode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine without any runtime faults.Sorry for using Bruteforce approach.
The code for printPretty() is available at
http://leetcode.com/2010/09/how-to-pretty-print-binary-tree.html

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <math.h>   
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct BinaryTree {

  BinaryTree *left, *right;
  char data;
  BinaryTree(int val) : left(NULL), right(NULL), data(val) { }
  ~BinaryTree(){ this->left = NULL; this->right = NULL ;  }

};
BinaryTree *createNode(char d)
{
    return new BinaryTree(d);
}
#define MAX     256
int indexOf[MAX];

void inorderIndex(char *IN,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        indexOf[ (int)IN[i] ] = i;
    }
    return;
}

int searchIndex(char arr[], int strt, int end, char value)
{
    int i;
    for(i = strt; i <= end; i++)
        if(arr[i] == value)
          return i;
    return -1;
}

BinaryTree *INLEVEL(char *in,char *level,int in_st,int in_end,int lev_st,int lev_end)
{

    int idx=-1,i,left_lev_idx=-1,right_lev_idx=-1;
    if(level[lev_st] == '\0' )
        return NULL;

    idx = searchIndex(in,in_st,in_end,level[lev_st] );
    if(idx == -1)
        return NULL;

    BinaryTree*root=createNode( level[lev_st] );
//  root->data = level[st];
    root->left = root->right = NULL;

    for ( i = lev_st+1; i <= lev_end ; i++)
    {
        if ( (indexOf[ (int) level[i] ] > idx) && (indexOf[ (int) level[i] ] <= in_end ) )
            if(right_lev_idx == -1)
                right_lev_idx = i;

        if ( (indexOf[ (int) level[i] ] < idx) && (indexOf[ (int) level[i] ] >= in_st ) )
            if(left_lev_idx == -1)
                left_lev_idx = i;

    }
    if(left_lev_idx != -1)
        root->left = INLEVEL(in,level,in_st,idx-1,left_lev_idx,lev_end);

    if(right_lev_idx != -1)
        root->right = INLEVEL(in,level,idx+1,in_end,right_lev_idx,lev_end);

    return root;
}

int main() 
{
     char IN[100] ="DBFEAGCLJHK"
    ,LEVEL[100]="ABCDEGHFJKL";
    BinaryTree *root =(BinaryTree *) NULL;
    inorderIndex(IN,strlen(IN) );
    root=INLEVEL(IN,LEVEL,0,strlen(IN)-1,0,strlen(IN)-1 );
//      printPretty(root, 2, 0, cout);      


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static tree MakeTreeFromInorderAndLevelOrder(int[] inorder,int[] lorder,int s,int n,int cnt1) {
    if(s>n || s>=inorder.length || n>=inorder.length || cnt1>=inorder.length) {
        return null;
    }
    int mIndex = Search(lorder[cnt1],inorder,s,n);
    tree t = new tree(lorder[cnt1]);

    cnt1 = 2*cnt1 + 1;
    t.left = MakeTreeFromInorderAndLevelOrder(inorder,lorder,s,mIndex-1,cnt1);
    //Boundary case
    if(cnt1<inorder.length && t.left==null) {
        t.right =   MakeTreeFromInorderAndLevelOrder(inorder,lorder,mIndex+1,n,cnt1);
    }
    else {
    cnt1 -=1;
    cnt1 /=2;
    cnt1 = 2*cnt1 + 2;
    t.right = MakeTreeFromInorderAndLevelOrder(inorder,lorder,mIndex+1,n,cnt1);
    //Boundary case
    if(t.right ==null && cnt1<inorder.length) {
        t.left = MakeTreeFromInorderAndLevelOrder(inorder,lorder,s,mIndex-1,cnt1);
    }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class InorderLevelorder {

private static int[] levelArray;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //in order traversal of binary tree
    int[] in = {4,10,3,1,7,11,8,2};

    //level order traversal of binary tree
    int[] lev = {7,10,2,4,3,8,1,11};

    //Builds a Binary Tree and returns the root node
    buildTree(in, lev);
}

private static BinaryTreeNode buildTree(int[] in, int[] lev){

    //Hash the values of both the arrays for O(1) time search
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> inMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> levMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    levelArray = lev;
    for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++)
        inMap.put(in[i], i);
    for(int j=0;j<lev.length;j++)
        levMap.put(lev[j], j);
    return buildTree(in, lev, 0, in.length - 1, inMap, levMap);
}

//recursive method that constructs the binary tree
private static BinaryTreeNode buildTree(int[] in, int[] lev, int inStart, int inEnd, HashMap<Integer, Integer> inMap, HashMap<Integer, Integer> levMap){

    if(inStart > inEnd)
        return null;

    int nodeVal = lev[0];
    BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode();
    node.setData(nodeVal);

    if(inStart == inEnd)
        return node;

    int inIndex = inMap.get(nodeVal);
    int[] leftSubTree = subArray(in, levelArray, inStart, inIndex-1, inMap, levMap);
    int[] rightSubTree = subArray(in, levelArray, inIndex+1, inEnd, inMap, levMap);

    node.setLeftNode(buildTree(in, leftSubTree, inStart, inIndex-1, inMap, levMap));
    node.setRightNode(buildTree(in, rightSubTree, inIndex+1, inEnd, inMap, levMap));

    return node;
}

private static int[] subArray(int[] in, int[] lev, int inStart, int inEnd, HashMap<Integer, Integer> inMap, HashMap<Integer, Integer> levMap){

    int[] newSubArray = new int[inEnd - inStart + 1];
    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=inStart;i<=inEnd;i++){
        int levIndex = levMap.get(in[i]);
        set.add(levIndex);
    }
    int j=0;
    Iterator<Integer> iter = set.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        int levIndex = iter.next();
        int levValue = lev[levIndex];
        newSubArray[j] = levValue;
        j++;
    }

    return newSubArray;
}
}

class BinaryTreeNode {

private int data;
private BinaryTreeNode leftNode;
private BinaryTreeNode rightNode;

public int getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public BinaryTreeNode getLeftNode() {
    return leftNode;
}
public void setLeftNode(BinaryTreeNode leftNode) {
    this.leftNode = leftNode;
}
public BinaryTreeNode getRightNode() {
    return rightNode;
}
public void setRightNode(BinaryTreeNode rightNode) {
    this.rightNode = rightNode;
}

}
```